# how to change an array structure in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array below in php:

```
$input = [
        'google.com',
        'microsoft.com',
        [ 
            'google.com' => 'cloud',
            'microsoft.com' => 'office',
        ],
        [
            'microsoft.com' => 'azure',
        ],
         [
            'office' => ['word', 'excel'],
        ],
        
    ];
```

And I want to convert it to the format below:

```
$output = [
    'google.com' => [
        'cloud'
    ],
    'microsoft.com'  => [ 
        'office' => ['word', 'excel'],
        'azure'
    ],
    
];
```

I tried to do it recursively but I failed. Is there an efficient way to do so?

Comment: Can you share the code you tried ?

Comment: It's actually not complete. I don't expect it to work

Comment: I edited the $output

Comment: Asking for efficiency suggests you have a working algorithm that doesn't perform as you need, so I guess you just want a way to do it. It's also unclear if you mention recursivity because the structure can be deeply nested. Without further details, all I can suggest is to check array values with `is_array()`.

Comment: What's the logic behind the starting array? They appear to be in some kind of order, but it is unclear to me what formats are allowed, and if there is a guaranteed order in which those values appear in that array

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much about the original input array order, here's a basic way to do this. It iterates over the `$input` 3 times (which may not be necessary if we knew more about the logic of the input array, but this ensures that any "nested" values have already been assigned in a previous pass). Each pass is noted on the input array.

```
$input = [
    'google.com', // non-array, first pass
    'microsoft.com', // non-array, first pass
    // root, second pass
    [ 
        'google.com' => 'cloud',
        'microsoft.com' => 'office',
    ],
    // root, second pass
    [
        'microsoft.com' => 'azure',
    ],
    // nested, third pass
    [
        'office' => ['word', 'excel'],
    ],
];
```

The first pass finds and sets the non-array values and then removes them from the input for faster 2nd and 3rd passes.

The second pass finds and sets the array values with non-array keys and then removes them from the input for a faster 3rd pass. This pass also keeps track of the reverse `product => domain` relationships so we don't need to search through the output array in the 3rd pass.

The third pass uses the lookup from the 2nd pass to assign the product array to the correct domain. Subsequently, we remove the previously-set product from the output to avoid the same associative key and indexed value as commented in the code.

To be more explicit with the output, you're actually looking for a mix of indexed/associative keys:

```
$output = [
    'google.com' => [
        0 => 'cloud'
    ],
    'microsoft.com'  => [ 
        'office' => ['word', 'excel'],
        1 => 'azure'
    ],
    
];
```

```
<?php

$input = [
    'google.com', // non-array, first pass
    'microsoft.com', // non-array, first pass
    // root, second pass
    [ 
        'google.com' => 'cloud',
        'microsoft.com' => 'office',
    ],
    // root, second pass
    [
        'microsoft.com' => 'azure',
    ],
    // nested, third pass
    [
        'office' => ['word', 'excel'],
    ],
];
    
$output = [];

// lookup table to keep track of domain/products so we don't need to search the output array to find the correct domain
$lookup = [];

// first pass to set non-array values
foreach($input as $key => $val) {
    if (!is_array($val)) {
        $input[$key] = '';
        // remove this key for faster future passes
        unset($input[$key]);
    }
}

// second pass to assign all root keys
foreach($input as $key => $val) {
    foreach($val as $domain => $product) {
        // take care of these on the 3rd pass
        if (is_array($product)) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $output[$domain][] = $product;
        $lookup[$product] = $domain; // for faster processing in the third pass

        // remove this key for faster future passes
        unset($input[$key][$domain]);

        // don't leave empty values around
        if (empty($input[$key])) {
            unset($input[$key]);
        }
    }
}

// third pass to assign nested values
foreach($input as $key => $val) {
    foreach($val as $key2 => $val2) {
        // if we didn't use the $lookup here, the alternative would be
        // to iterate over $output and its values to find the matching
        // product, and then use that key (domain) to assign $val2
        // but using the lookup is cleaner/faster because we can set
        // the array key directly

        $domain = $lookup[$key2];
        $output[$domain][$key2] = $val2;

        // now we need to unset the found value, or else we end up with:
        // [0 => 'office', 'office' => [...]]
        $foundKey = array_search($key2, $output[$domain]);
        unset($output[$domain][$foundKey]);
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

Working demo at https://3v4l.org/lE7gT